# Why does macro expansion add a space sometimes?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

If I do this:

```
#define F a
F/
```

It expands to `a/` [<kbd>godbolt</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/reGxqz)

If I do this:

```
#define F /
F/
```

It expands to `/ /` with a space in between [<kbd>goodbolt</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nYhzGn)

But if I convert it to a string, and print it, it doesn't add any spaces [<kbd>goodbolt</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bTnsnK):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_IMPL(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_IMPL(x)

#define F /


int main() {
  puts(STR(F/));
}
```

Why is there a space in between, but only some of the time? Is it allowed to add more spaces in other cases?

Comment: I believe the purpose is to ensure that symbols are separated. `//` is comment while `/  /` is operator `/` written twice.

Comment: In both cases, the amount of whitespace inserted is unspecified.   However, a macro expansion is not allowed to start or end a comment.

Comment: I think there _are_ preprocessors that do not add spaces.

Comment: for bonus points, put trailing whitespace on the `#define F /` line and repeat the stringization

Comment: @M.M leading and trailing spaces shouldn't matter, right? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3dKo1Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language specification is like this, at a high level:

- Break up the input into a sequence of tokens.
- Run the preprocessor on that sequence of tokens (resulting in another sequence of tokens)
- Compile that resulting sequence of tokens.

There is no specification of any intermediate plain-text representation between the steps . What you are seeing in the "preprocessor output" is entirely at the whim of the vendor,  so long as the final result of the whole translation process behaves as specified.

---

Analysis of the example with `#define F /` and `STR(F/)` :

First note that `#define F /` followed by newline means that `F` is replaced by the two tokens *w* `/`  (where I am using *w* to mean a whitespace token).

The sequence of preprocessing tokens for `STR(F/)` after tokenization is:

- `STR`, `(`, `F`, `/`, `)`

After the first round of macro substitution the tokens are:

- *w*, `STR_IMPL`, `(`, *w*, `/`, `/`, `)`

After the second round, the tokens are:

- *w*, `"//"` .

The definition of the `#` preprocessing operator includes that leading whitespace is removed. So the token sequence *w*, `/`, `/` becomes `"//"`, not `" //"`.

There was never any space between the `F/` or the two slashes at any point.

Comment: What if I convert it to a string? Then it's visible behavior https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8o1KEs

Comment: And converting to string seems to remove the space in this case

Comment: I will add analysis of that example to my answer

Comment: Whitespace isn't a token.

Answer (score 5):

Macros work on the token level. Spaces are added when printing the result in string form to disambiguate.

`F/` is two tokens, `F` and `/`. After macro expansion, it still needs to be two tokens, `/` and `/`. But if you print them next to each other, it becomes `//`, which is just one token (a comment). So there needs to be a space in-between.

Long story short: yes, macro expansion can add spaces, because spaces don't matter at the level macros operate at.

Comment: Hmm. Can they add spaces even when not necessary? Could the first example expand to `a /`? Can they add any number of spaces, or just one?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - Short answer, yes.

Comment: Why does it not add a space if I convert the result to string? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bTnsnK

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Succinctly put, because "convert to string" using `#` is defined to care about whether there is whitespace between tokens.