# Why do I get a compiler error when creating macro like this?

Tags: c++, macros

My purpose is to get a comment using macros.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define SIGN /

int main() {
    SIGN* AHA *SIGN
    
}
```

I expect it to be a comment like this

```
/*AHA*/
```

How can I have that in macros so that I can give the comment text to it and it will make a comment for me.

Comment: If you look at the macro expansion, I expect it will show something more like `/ *AHA */`

Comment: Yes it does, and is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: I don't know that it is. What's the purpose?

Comment: Creating a problem that doesn't need to be created. Have fun with it :)

Comment: Just learning about macros and wondered why that didn't work if that is actually just text copy

Comment: Read some C++ standard, like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or something newer

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419826/why-does-macro-expansion-add-a-space-sometimes) might be of interest.

Comment: wish it was possible to have such a software maybe online which would create those definitions for you

Comment: The comments, both C and C++ styles, are removed at the preprocessor stage, in fact just before replacing macros. It is therefore impossible to generate a comment with a macro. But this is never necessary !

Comment: I don't understand.  Making a macro that is 4 letters that is a synonym for one character.  It's not a short-cut, typo or productivity macro.

Comment: No it is totally impossible to achieve what you want. This is by design.